# C# How to transfer data from Parent Form to Child User Control

Tags: c#, forms, panel

I have a Parent Form and all my child forms are User Controls aka Panels
I call them using this code

```
  private void monitor_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonBackToDefaultColor(SystemColors.HotTrack);
        monitor_btn.BackColor = LightYellow;
        pm.BringToFront();
    }
```

I also have this snippet of inside of the public partial class ParentForm

```
 public product_monitoring pm = new product_monitoring();
```

Now I want to transfer the value of label1.Text in my parent form to my child user control which can be activated by the button click event of the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a property in the user control that is set by the form.

In usercontrol: `public string LabelText{get;set;}`

In `monitor_btn_Click(...)`: `usercontrol.LabelText = label1.Text;`

Comment: The code, That is the same code I use when transfering data from form to form, sadly It doesn't work here even if I put in the load method

label1.Text = LabelText;

Comment: Could you be more specific. What happens when you try to do it this way? Is the property updated with the correct value but not reflected by the controls on the form? Have you tried to refresh the form by calling Invalidate();?

Comment: The value of the label from the parent form is not being set

Answer (score 0):

Declare a public static variable.

On click the parent set the variable value, every form get the value from that variable and set it.